# How to shell a coconut without breaking the seed?

Tags: coconut

Quite a lot of the time I'm able to get large parts of seeds by hitting the shell against the ground. This causes bigger cracks in the shell than the seed, I can then pry off the outer layer. However, I've never been able to get a whole seed this way.

The only other ways I can think of would be dissolving it in an acid or using abrasion, but I do not know if these would work.

**What is the best method of removing the dark outer shell from a coconut without damaging the inner white seed?**

Comment: Lasers probably also work, but that's more on an industrial scale.

Answer (score 1):

Freeze it and then break the shell careful with a hammer...

Answer (score 1):

Blessed Geek's videos show people cutting or cracking the coconut ... not separating the shell from the meat inside.

I've seen [video of someone doing it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftO1MYXY1wE), but they're working from a coconut with an undried husk, which aren't available except near where coconuts grow.  (and he's using some sort of a specialized flexible tool to get under the coconut).

You might try roasting the husked  coconut whole.  Normally I drain the liquid first, but that removes support for the meat while you're trying to pry off the shell.  (when roasted, the shell will dry out and crack, making it easier to remove the shell)