# Peeling coconut meat from shell

Tags: coconut

I roasted these two coconuts at 350℉ for about 15 min. 
[image]
I was hoping it would make it easier to detach the meat from the shell but it didn't so much. I peeled it but I struggled with a butter knife. Is there a way to cook it differently to make it easier to peel or is there a better tool than a butter knife?

Comment: related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/28556/how-to-shell-a-coconut-without-breaking-the-seed?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Cross-hatch it several times with a sharp knife (every 2-3 cm or 1 inch).  Then you can pry up the chunks more easily.

Comment: Do you mean cross-hatch the meat or the shell?

Comment: Cut the shell in half.  Cross-hatch the meat from the inside.